# while joining two queries getting aggregate function error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two query
1->
`select top 10 * from transaction_tbl order by transactID desc`   this is i am using taking last 10 transaction from my transaction table
2->

```
select  avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.PAICdate )) as 
Average  from transaction_tbl t where locid=6
```

this query i am using for getting average time differnce between that two dates..
this two queries working fine..
i want to get only last 10 transactions average time differnce

so i try  join this two queries  like this:

```
select top 10 avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.PAICdate )) as Average
from transaction_tbl t
where locid = 6
group by transactID
order by transactID desc;
```

but i am getting result something like this:
[image]

i want to get total average of last 10 records

Comment: . . Please edit the question and add sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested query like this:

```
select  avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.PAICdate )) as Average  
from (
    select top 10 * from transaction_tbl where locid=6 order by transactID desc
) t
```

Comment: this is working fine..sir if i get average something like less than 12.5 then i want to show 12 or if i get average greater 12.5 then i want to show 13..is this possible here??

Comment: Certainly, just use the ROUND() function, for example: `select round(12.5, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group by `TransactId`:

```
select top 10 avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.PAICdate )) as Average
from transaction_tbl t
where locid = 6
group by transactID
order by transactID desc;
```

Your query is failing because `TransactID` is not known after the aggregation.

Comment: this time i am getting 10 records of result..i want to get total average time in minutes